# Wordpress jquery seems to load but does not function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am adding a jquery script to a wordpress site Im working on

I setup wordpress enque to add jquery, my chrome Wappapyzer plugin recognizes jquery on site, I run each fade command separately on my list and it doesn't do anything but there are not mistakes on the console.

Here is my script.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#btn_eng').click(function(){
             jQuery("#txz_eng").fadeIn();
             jQuery("#txz_brz").fadeOut();
             jQuery("#txz_l3" ).fadeOut();
             jQuery("#txz_l4" ).fadeOut();
        });
        jQuery('#btn_brz').click(function(){
             jQuery("#txz_eng").fadeOut();
             jQuery("#txz_brz").fadeIn();
             jQuery("#txz_l3" ).fadeOut();
             jQuery("#txz_l4" ).fadeOut();
        });
        jQuery('#btn_l3').click(function(){
             jQuery("#txz_eng").fadeOut();
             jQuery("#txz_brz").fadeOut();
             jQuery("#txz_l3" ).fadeIn();
             jQuery("#txz_l4" ).fadeOut();
        });
        jQuery('#btn_l4').click(function(){
             jQuery("#txz_eng").fadeOut();
             jQuery("#txz_brz").fadeOut();
             jQuery("#txz_l3" ).fadeOut();
             jQuery("#txz_l4" ).fadeIn();
        });
});
</script>
```

Wierdly when I do a regular document.getElementById('someId') it accepts the command with no error but does not give a response.

Comment: "but gives no mistakes there anyway." == there are no errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, no errors on the console.

Comment: Don't use language="JavaScript" its deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the comments above were helpful, but I had a typo. It was supposed to be txt instead of txz in the id tags.

Comment: Be sure to accept your own answer as correct in order to close this issue.

Answer (score 1):

try to add new line

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

in your jQuery file e.g. /jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2

then change jQuery alias to $ like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#btn_eng').click(function(){ $("#txz_eng").fadeIn();
    $("#txz_brz").fadeOut();
    $("#txz_l3" ).fadeOut();
    $("#txz_l4" ).fadeOut();
    });
// and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might recomend a function too:

```
$('#btn_eng').on('click', {
    element: "txt_eng"
}, fadeStuff);
$('#btn_brz').on('click', {
    element: "txt_brz"
}, fadeStuff);
$('#btn_l3').on('click', {
    element: "txt_13"
}, fadeStuff);
$('#btn_l4').on('click', {
    element: "txt_14"
}, fadeStuff);

function fadeStuff(event) {
    $("#txt_eng").fadeOut();
    $("#txt_brz").fadeOut();
    $("#txt_13").fadeOut();
    $("#txt_14").fadeOut();
    $("#" + event.data.element).fadeIn();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/5R8Gq/